# Ext.String.format enhancement in EXTJS

Tags: extjs4

I am new to ExtJS. I came across following piece of code:

```
Ext.String.format('<a href="mailto:{0}">{1}</a>',value+"@abc.com",value);
```

Now this will create a mailto link. But my query is that how Ext.String.format works and what else can I use it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Ext.String.format`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.String-method-format):

> Allows you to define a tokenized string and pass an arbitrary number
>   of arguments to replace the tokens. Each token must be unique, and
>   must increment in the format {0}, {1}, etc.

You can look at the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/String2.html#Ext-String-method-format) of the function and see it uses the `formatRe` regex (`/\{(\d+)\}/g`):

```
format: function(format) {
        var args = Ext.Array.toArray(arguments, 1);
        return format.replace(formatRe, function(m, i) {
            return args[i];
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allows you to define a tokenized string and pass an arbitrary number of arguments to replace the tokens. Each token must be unique, and must increment in the format {0}, {1}, etc.

The following Ext.String.format is modified to accept formatters functions (Ext.util.Format)
e.g.
alert(Ext.String.format("{0} {1:usMoney} {2:date('Y-m-d')}", 10, 20, new Date()));

Here is modified code
Code:

Ext.String._formatRe = /{(\d+)(?:\:([\w.]*)(?:((.*?)?))?)?}/g;
        Ext.String._argRe = /(['"])(.*?)\1\s*(?:,|$)/g

```
    Ext.String.format = function(format) {
        var args = Ext.Array.toArray(arguments, 1),
            fm = Ext.util.Format;

        return format.replace(Ext.String._formatRe, function(m, idx, fn, fmArgs) {
            var replaceValue = args[parseInt(idx, 10)],
                values,
                match;

            if (fn) {
                values = [replaceValue];

                while (match = Ext.String._argRe.exec(fmArgs)) {
                    values.push(match[2]);
                }

                return fm[fn].apply(fm, values);
            }

            return replaceValue;
        });
    };
```